# Fourier series of an arbitrary function of a cosine function

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, taylor-series

Is there a general expression for the Fourier series of the function $f(a\cos(\omega t))$ in terms of the derivatives of $f$? Obviously, the function can be expressed as a Maclaurin series $f(0)+af'(0)\cos(\omega t)+\frac{1}{2}a^2 f''(0)\cos^2(\omega t)+\cdots$. Then by expressing the powers of cosine functions as Fourier series and rearranging the sum, in principle we can obtain the Fourier series of $f(a\cos(\omega t))$ in terms of the derivatives of $f$. However, I am not sure whether this Fourier series can be expressed in a simple way, like a series where the coefficients are just some special functions.

Comment: That approach will work only if $f$ is analytic in the disk of radius bigger than $a$. If you know the Fourier expansion of $f$, it may be more efficient though still quite a mess. I doubt there is anything really good. What do you need it for?

Answer (score 1):

$$f(a\cos(\omega t))=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}i^n\left[J_n\left(-ia\frac{d}{dx}\right)f(x)\right]_{x=0}e^{in\omega t}$$
where $J_n(x)$ is the Bessel function. This expression can be checked with a special example: the Jacobi–Anger expansion.
The following derivation of this expression can be found at [Fourier Series of an Arbitrary Function of
Cosine and Sine](https://1drv.ms/w/s!ArzsJGtUcNf0xRjeKX6MZinZoGtv?e=Bfumvh):

The function $f(a\cos(\omega t))$ can be expressed as a Maclaurin series:
$$
f(a\cos(\omega t)) =
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac1{n!}\left(\frac{d^n f(x)}{dx^n}\right)_{x = 0}a^n\cos^n(\omega t) =
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac1{n!}\left(\frac{d^n f(x)}{dx^n}\right)_{x = 0}a^n\left(\frac{e^{i\omega t} + e^{-i\omega t}}2\right)^n =
\sum_{n = 0}^\infty \frac1{n!}\left[\left(\frac a 2\frac d{dx}\right)^n\right]_{x = 0}\sum_{m = 0}^n C^n_m e^{i(n - 2m)\omega t}.
$$
Therefore, the Fourier coefficient of the base $e^{i k\omega t}$ can be expressed as
$$
\sum_{m = 0}^n \frac1{(2m + k)!}C^{2m + k}_m\left[\left(\frac a 2\frac d{dx}\right)^{2m + k}\right]_{x = 0} =
i^k\sum_{m = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^m}{m!(m + k)!}\left[\left(-i\frac a 2\frac d{dx}\right)^{2m + k}\right]_{x = 0} =
i^k\left.J_k\left(-i a\frac d{dx}\right)f(x)\right\rvert_{x = 0}.
$$

Comment: A link to a OneDrive document seems like a very fragile way to store this information, so I typed the relevant portion in this answer (and took the liberty of correcting an obvious typo $i^l$ → $i^k$).  I hope that was all right.